# How to delete SPO sites by URL web address not site name in PS

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have several SharePoint online sites (hundreds) every about 4 of them are created with the same name/title but they differ in the url web address. Now I need to delete specific one of each 4 which I have the URL address in a spreadsheet, so is it possible to delete them with specifying the url in the Powershell script instead of the name/title? I hope it's possible because it will take forever to check each site individual and delete the correct one.

For example the sites look like this:

AAA - .../siteaaa1

AAA - .../siteaaa2

AAA - .../siteaaa3

AAA - .../siteaaa4

ABB - .../siteabb1

ABB - .../siteabb2

and so on..

Will be great help if someone know how.

Many thanks

Comment: are these subsites or site collections ?

Comment: They are subsites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete an individual subsite using urls, you can use the below code in powershell:

```
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/siteAA1"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)

$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$web = $Context.Web  

$Context.Load($web)  
$Context.ExecuteQuery() 

$web.DeleteObject() 
$Context.ExecuteQuery() 
Write-Host $web.Title "Site Deleted"
```

Or if you know the urls, you can specify them in an array and then delete them via server relative url as below:

```
#enter the site collection url
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/"


#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#enter server relative path of the subsite in the array
#for first level subsite, it will be "siteaa1" - url would be ""https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/siteaa1"
#for second level subsite, it will be "subsite/siteaa1" - url would be ""https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/subsite/siteaa1"

$array = @("siteaaa1", "siteaaa2", "siteaaa3")
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) 
{

    $web = $Context.Site.OpenWeb($array[$i]);

    $Context.Load($web)  
    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 

    $web.DeleteObject() 
    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 
    Write-Host $web.Title "Site Deleted"

}
```

Download & install the SharePoint client component SDK  which will give you the CSOM dlls.

Also download the SP online management shell to run the above code.

[SharePoint 2013 Client component SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

[SharePoint online management shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

Comment: Gautam you are a GENIUS :)

One last thing, if I have the list of "sites" to delete in a csv column, how can I add it in the array?

Comment: @Blueman - you can refer this link - [How to load list data in a SharePoint Online List from a CSV File](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-load-list-data-in-a-ddafec31) and modify the code accordingly.